# `jQuery.parseJSON` function in only javascript (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking for the method to do `jQuery.parseJSON` in JavaScript that parses a json to return a JavaScript object. I can't use jQuery since the whole plugin that I have built is standalone JS and no jQuery has been used till now. Is there something of this sort that's already provided in JavaScript?

Comment: @KevinB : Editted the question. I intended to mention jQuery.parseJSON

Comment: My comment still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the native JSON object (this is the only time it is correct to say "JSON object", it is literally an object named `JSON`) to manipulate JSON strings.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Use `JSON.parse(yourJSONString);` to serialize and `JSON.stringify(yourJSONObject);` to deserialize.

If you look at the [jQuery core source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js) on line 492, `jQuery.parseJSON` is just an alias to `JSON.parse`.

Comment: `jbabey` Editted the question. I intended to mention jQuery.parseJSON

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the [native JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON), which is supported in most browsers, but you will run into an issue when you try to use it in the dinosaur browsers such as IE7 and lower. There is the option to [include a standalone plugin that mimics native functionality here (JSON.js).](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

Use the browser native method [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON)

```
window.JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

**Long answer:**

To get it working in old browsers, you can take the  [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js) of `jQuery.parseJSON` and remove any dependencies on jQuery itself. Here is a working standalone version:

```
function standaloneParseJson ( data ) {
    // Attempt to parse using the native JSON parser first
    if ( window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ) {
        return window.JSON.parse( data );
    }

    if ( data === null ) {
        return data;
    }

    var rvalidchars = /^[\],:{}\s]*$/;
    var rvalidbraces = /(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g;
    var rvalidescape = /\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[\da-fA-F]{4})/g;
    var rvalidtokens = /"[^"\\\r\n]*"|true|false|null|-?(?:\d+\.|)\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+|)/g;

    if ( typeof data === "string" ) {

        // Make sure leading/trailing whitespace is removed (IE can't handle it)
        data = data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

        if ( data ) {
            // Make sure the incoming data is actual JSON
            // Logic borrowed from http://json.org/json2.js
            if ( rvalidchars.test( data.replace( rvalidescape, "@" )
                .replace( rvalidtokens, "]" )
                .replace( rvalidbraces, "")) ) {

                return ( new Function( "return " + data ) )();
            }
        }
    }

    // Error code here
    //jQuery.error( "Invalid JSON: " + data );
}
```